# How do I create Javascript object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying the create the following:

```
var deal_info = {
    "1": {
        "deal": {
            "deal_id": "1",
            "qty": "1",
            "option_price_sale": "7900",
            "price_ship": "2500",
            "ship_price_type": "1"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "deal": {
            "deal_id": "2",
            "qty": "1",
            "option_price_sale": "3880",
            "price_ship": "2500",
            "ship_price_type": "1"
        }
    }
};
```

I started with

```
var deal_info = {};
```

How do I continue to create the array dynamically?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)?

Comment: deal_info is an object.

Comment: There are no arrays in any of the code you've shown.  `{}` denotes a javascript object.  You would need `[]` for an array.  It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: oh my god!sorry array is a typo...

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Why are you using an object with integer-value keys, rather than an array?

Comment: @Tom no no We conducted a small project.

Comment: @JasonBaker it's product ID...So what should I do?

Comment: @SukyumKim Without knowing a lot more about the semantics of your use case, I can't say for sure. I suspect that each `deal` should contain the ProductId involved in the deal, and then I would leave it at that; storing each deal by ProductId makes it very easy to find all the deals associated with a product (As long as each deal is only for one product), but otherwise doesn't do much optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is not an array, that is an object that has a 2 properties

```
"1" : {                 
            "deal" : {
                "deal_id" : "1",                        
                "qty" : "1",
                "option_price_sale" : "7900",
                "price_ship" : "2500",
                "ship_price_type" : "1"                     
            }
        }
```

and

```
"2" : {
            "deal" : {
                "deal_id" : "2",                        
                "qty" : "1",
                "option_price_sale" : "3880",
                "price_ship" : "2500",
                "ship_price_type" : "1"                     
            }
        }
```

to make it an array it should be

```
var deal_info = [
        {                 
            "deal" : {
                "deal_id" : "1",                        
                "qty" : "1",
                "option_price_sale" : "7900",
                "price_ship" : "2500",
                "ship_price_type" : "1"                     
            }
        },

        {
            "deal" : {
                "deal_id" : "2",                        
                "qty" : "1",
                "option_price_sale" : "3880",
                "price_ship" : "2500",
                "ship_price_type" : "1"                     
            }
        }
    ];
```

and as mentioned you can push new objects like

```
deal_info.push({"3" : {
            "deal" : {
                "deal_id" : "3",                        
                "qty" : "1",
                "option_price_sale" : "3880",
                "price_ship" : "2500",
                "ship_price_type" : "1"                     
            }
        }});
```

Comment: now I think about it, I can understand that. thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1):

```
var deal_info = {};

deal_info["1"] = {};
deal_info["1"]["deal"] = {};
```

Comment: oh my god!thanks sabithpocker!!!